# "Cluster" Code Help in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am relative newcomer to SQL, but have gained many useful ideas through the site.  Now I'm stuck on a piece of code that seems simple enough, but for some reason I can't wrap my head around it.

I am trying to create a third column (Column Z) based off of the first two columns below:

```
Column X   Column Y
-------------------
 1          a
 1          b
 1          c
 2          a
 2          d
 2          e
 2          f
 4          b
 5          i
 5          c
 3          g
 3          h
 6          j
 6          k
 6          l
```

What i need to have happen in Column Z:

> - For each individual value found in Column Y, note the value of Column X
> - Likewise, for each individual value in Column X, note the value of Column Y
> - Then, cluster (RANK/ROW_NUMBER?) these into groups seen below:

```
Column X   Column Y  Column Z
-----------------------------
 1          a         1
 1          b         1
 1          c         1
 2          a         1
 2          d         1
 2          e         1
 2          f         1
 4          b         1
 5          i         1
 5          c         1
 3          g         2
 3          h         2
 6          j         3
 6          k         3
 6          l         3
```

I hope I've been clear enough without over-complicating things.  My head has been spinning all morning.  Let me know if anyone needs any more info.

Greatly appreciated in advance!

Comment: I don't understand (just from the sample data you're showing) what the logic is behind your column Z.... why does it switch from 1 to 2 after the values (5, c) ? What makes the next row change the value? That's totally not clear from just the data ...... please explain further

Comment: Hi Marc,
Because neither 3 nor g appeared previously.
(5, c) shows up in Column Z under 1 because c is also found in (1,c), so it's clustered with the rest.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Why would (5, i) not fall in a 'new' cluster then, that's the first time both 5 and i occur in the list right? I still don't get it :-)

Comment: @Josien Because `i` is connected to `5`, and `5` is connected to `c`. OP wants to group all separated paths (I don't know proper name for this structure).

Comment: Ooooh wait... You're doing some sort of 'mutually exclusive grouping' thing. First grouping the data set (based on "We belong with each other 'cause we're linked") to determine the number of clusters, then 'sorting' into the clusters.

Comment: Good question - that's because (5,c) contains c, which also shows up in (1,c).  So because of that, (5,i) also needs to be grouped with the previous. (3,g) is the first unique set of values, likewise for (6,j).

Comment: Yes! Correct, Nikola & Josien

Comment: will they be sorted by x,y alphabetically, or is there an independent sort field?  If they were sorted alphabetically, (4,b), (5,i), and (5,c) would be 2 instead of 1 because of (3,g).

Comment: that was quite a challange +1 for the simplicity

Comment: I found my error, I am trying to correct it, not sure i can due to circular references

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced exactly this problem for some analyses in the past.  The only way I could get it to work is by doing a loop, that incrementally adds in the information.

The loop assigns the minimum "x" value within each group as the group id.  By your rules, this is guaranteed to be unique.  It starts by assigning the current x value to z.  It then finds the minimum z along the x and y dimensions.  It repeats this process until no records change.

Given your data, the following is an outline of how to do it:

```
update t set z = x

while 1=1
begin
    with toupdate as (
         select t.*,
                min(z) over (partition by x) as idx,
                min(z) over (partition by y) as idy from t
         )
    update toupdate
        set z = (case when idx < idy then idx else idy end)
        where z > idx or z > idy;
    if (@@ROWCOUNT = 0) break;   
end;

;with a as
(
  select z, dense_rank() over (order by z) newZ from t
)
update a set z = newZ
```

Comment: @joshF if my query still gives the wrong result, I surgest you try Gordons' script. I changed it so it works. It seems correct now.

Comment: +1 I guess it worked better than my script, @joshF seemed content

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: this works perfectly!  big thanks to everyone who contributed solutions, guidance, and help.  wonderful community!

Comment: @t-clausen.dk of course!  i can send you the specific data i used.  how would i go about doing that?  i don't see anywhere on here to send attachments or the like.  is there site protocol for things of this nature?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the best way, but it works

SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/99532/1

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS row_nb
    FROM    #t
)
, c2 AS (
    SELECT e1.*
    ,CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM cte e2 WHERE e1.Y = e2.Y and e2.row_nb < e1.row_nb) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as ex
FROM cte e1 
)
, c3 AS (
    SELECT  X,1 - SIGN(SUM(ex)) as ex,MAX(row_nb) as max_row_nb
    FROM    c2
    GROUP BY X
)
SELECT  
    cte.X,cte.Y
    ,(SELECT SUM(cc3.ex) FROM c3 cc3 where cc3.max_row_nb<= c3.max_row_nb) AS Z 
FROM    cte 
INNER JOIN c3 
    ON  c3.X = cte.X
ORDER BY cte.row_nb
```

Comment: it looks very promising, but i think you have to sort the data first, otherwise it will group it wrong. Try adding  (5,'a') to your test data

Comment: @t-clausen.dk, you are absolutely right. I can not see the real sort order from OP's give test data. I have to use ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))  to get first row_number.

Comment: You are missing the recusive part, which may be the reason it can't work. Check my solution for details

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @t table (x tinyint, y char(1), z tinyint)
insert @t (x,y) values(1,'a'),(1,'b'),(1,'c'),(2,'a'),(2,'d'),(2,'e'),(2,'c'),
(2,'f'),(4,'b'),(5,'i'),(5,'c'),(3,'g'),(3,'h'),(6,'j'),(6,'k'),(6,'l'),(7,'v')

;with a as
(
  select x,parent from 
  (
    select x, min(x) over (partition by y) parent from @t
  ) a
  where x > parent
), b as
(
  select x, parent from a
  union all
  select a.x, b.parent
  from a join b on a.parent = b.x
), c as
(

  select x, min(parent) parent
  from b
  group by x
), d as
(
  select t.x,t.y, t.z, 
  dense_rank() over (order by coalesce(c.parent, t.x)) calculatedZ 
  from @t t 
  left join c on t.x = c.x
)
select x,y,calculatedZ as z from d
-- if you want to update instead of selecting, replace last line with: 
-- update d set z = newz
-- select x,y,z from @t
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Result:

```
x y z
1 a 1
1 b 1
1 c 1
2 a 1
2 d 1
2 e 1
2 c 1
2 f 1
4 b 1
5 i 1
5 c 1
3 g 2
3 h 2
6 j 3
6 k 3
6 l 3
8 j 3
7 v 4
```

Comment: @JoshF no, take the whole script and execute it, it works very well, also being the best solution. This script requires sql server 2008+ because of the insert in the beginning. Otherwise you just need version 2005

Comment: i found this to be the best of the answers so far. however, using my complete set of data and not the test data supplied, it doesn't quite give the correct output, but it's really close.  the correct output was achieved via highly-inefficient excel formulas.  this was done to make sure the SQL produced the desired outputs.

Comment: This seems indeed the best solution, also giving good results with different data sets (unlike EricZ's solution). @JoshF: what sort of data in your complete set is not correctly sorted?

Comment: @JoshF this will give you the correct result no matter how complicated your data is, I suspect your code is giving you the wrong data to compare with

Comment: is there a way to post/send a file with my data (some 350 rows?)  I have added two extra columns with the cluster numbering output from code supplied by @t-clausen.dk as well as the excel formula.

Comment: in the meantime, i've gone over the code and studied it a bit more.  i've gained a better sense of how the code works.  really appreciate the effort and expertise provided by everyone.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk the code is very clean and a great start, but can i still accept the answer knowing that it doesn't apply to a larger data set?

Comment: @JoshF: you can accept an answer (and/or upvote) if you feel it has helped you solve (part of) your problem. But don't feel obliged to accept, it's your choice. Also if you need more time to check or want to ask some more questions of the person that answered, just take your time.